# how to access object in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have JSON formatted like this :

```
 [{
    "jenis_jurnal": "pembayaran",
    "no_perkiraan": "2102-01-01",
    "nama": "Hutang Usaha",
    "keterangan": "PEMBAYARAN U\/ BIAYA NO: PP-2020-0104 TGL VOUCHER. 2021-01-01",
    "potongan": "250000",
    "potongan_note": "note potongan",
    "coa_potongan": "7104-01-01",
    "coa_lain": "5101-08-01",
    "biaya_lain_note": "ket biaya lain",
    "debet": "1650000",
    "kredit": "0",
    "username": "michaelb"
}]
```

and I return `jenis_jurnal`, like this:

```
$data->jenis_jurnal
```

but get an error:

> trying to get property of non object

Where is my code wrong?

Comment: How do you get `$data`?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your json data isn't object in PHP.
It is array.
So you should access like this:

```
$data[0]['jenis_jurnal'];//you should assign the json data to `$data`
```

Comment: You might also add information about making sure it's parsed. OP might be getting it as a string

Comment: Yeah, we can use this condition `is_array($data)`.